# Enable SQL Broker after Database Restore

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, database-restore, service-broker

I've restored SQL server database where it enabled SQL Broker Services. Now in Restored Database I need to re-enable these service in SQL Broker, after some online research I came to know that executing one or more query listed below might helps,

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET DISABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Now in what order I need to execute these Queries, I have two questions :

1. What will be the first query I need to execute
2. What will be the last query I required to execute?

Comment: First try understanding what those do(`new_broker,disable`) and how it effects you database

Comment: and I'm trying to do same, is there any reference to get same?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56938/what-does-alter-database-set-new-broker-do-is-there-anything-to-worry-abo

Comment: Thanks @TheGameiswar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do none of the above. Specifically, if I was trying to ensure that Service Broker was enabled after a restore, I'd specify that in the restore command. Either of:

```
restore database [yourDatabase] with recovery, enable_broker;
restore database [yourDatabase] with recovery, new_broker;
```

What informs the choice of which to use? If you want the restored database to maintain the same Service Broker identifier (GUID) after restore and keep any in-flight messages that were present when the backup was taken, use the first. If you want it to generate a new GUID and clear the in-flight messages, use the second.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Thul and TheGameiswar now I understand my question is fundamentally wrong and how Service Broker works.